# How to setup Xfig onto a Mac machine?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, eps

The user manual said that I need to

> Get the source of xfig (xfig.3.2.5-alpha3.full.tar.gz) and gunzip and untar the file: Either do: gunzip -c xfig.3.2.5-alpha3.full.tar.gz | tar xvf - or gunzip xfig.3.2.5-alpha3.full.tar.gz tar xvf xfig.3.2.5-alpha3.full.tar

It also said that

> There is a version of xfig ported to run on the MacIntosh under the Darwin port of XFree86.

But I didn't find how to setup the XFree86 and even the xfig since I am very new to either Mac OS or UNIX.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use a package manager like [Macports](https://www.macports.org/), [Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/), [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) etc.

For macports the steps are basically

1. Install macports from the correct .dmg from [here](https://www.macports.org/install.php)
2. Install Xcode
3. Update macports `sudo port selfupdate`
4. Check your shells have /opt/local/bin on the path before other directories
5. Install the xfig port `sudo port install xfig`

The other managers will have a similar set of instructions.

Comment: Thanks for your warmly reply. I installed xfig according to your advice. I met a problem when I used the xfig. When I draw a line, I clicked the left button of the mouse at first and clicked the right button at the end of the line. But the line is eliminated after I clicked the right button.

Comment: Mark's answer misses three steps:

2':  install the Xcode command-line tools: `xcode-select
 --install`

2": install Xquartz (X11 terminal software) from http://xquartz.macosforge.org/landing/

5': Enable three button mouse emulation in XQuartz options.

Comment: I should also add that Xquartz is only needed for OS X above 10.5.

Comment: how do you open xfig?

Answer (score 0):

When drawing a line in xfig, the right button is a cancel operation button.  To end the line, you press the middle button.  I'm not sure how you get a mac mouse to simulate the middle or the right button.

Comment: Select `XQuartz > Preferences > Input > Emulate three button mouse`.