# port command not found

Tags: macos, macports, bash, zshrc

I am trying to install `XFig` and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11791976/how-to-setup-xfig-onto-a-mac-machine). But when I tried to `sudo port selfupdate` I get the error `sudo: port: command not found`.

I am using `zsh` and tried to modify the path according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694395/sudo-port-command-not-found) in both `.zshrc` and `.bash_profile` but still no luck.

The current `PATH` in `.zshrc` file looks like this

`export PATH="/Users/chintanshah/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need `/opt/local/bin` in the `$PATH`.

To add to `$PATH`:

`export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. so my new PATh is like this `export PATH=“/opt/local/bin:/Users/chintanshah/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"`, but when I restart the Terminal, I get a message like `/Users/chintanshah/.zshrc:84: unmatched "`. So, I removed `/opt/local/bin` and the error disappears. Also, when I just type `/opt/local/bin/port` it launches `port`

Comment: You don't need any `"` characters at all.

Comment: The command for this is `export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH`